# MySQL command output too wide in command-line client

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu, terminal-emulator

I am using `mysql` command line client in terminal emulator `lxterminal` in Ubuntu. When I run the following command:

```
mysql> select * from routines where routine_name = "simpleproc";
```

The output is a mess:

[image: My current output]

But if I copy and paste it here, the output shows me a nice table:

```
mysql> select * from routines where routine_name = "simpleproc";

+---------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| SPECIFIC_NAME | ROUTINE_CATALOG | ROUTINE_SCHEMA | ROUTINE_NAME | ROUTINE_TYPE | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_SCALE | DATETIME_PRECISION | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | COLLATION_NAME | DTD_IDENTIFIER | ROUTINE_BODY | ROUTINE_DEFINITION                                     | EXTERNAL_NAME | EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE | PARAMETER_STYLE | IS_DETERMINISTIC | SQL_DATA_ACCESS | SQL_PATH | SECURITY_TYPE | CREATED             | LAST_ALTERED        | SQL_MODE                                                                                                                                  | ROUTINE_COMMENT | DEFINER        | CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT | COLLATION_CONNECTION | DATABASE_COLLATION |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| simpleproc    | def             | test           | simpleproc   | PROCEDURE    |           |                     NULL |                   NULL |              NULL |          NULL |               NULL | NULL               | NULL           | NULL           | SQL          | BEGIN


SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM CUSTOMERS1;

END | NULL          | NULL              | SQL             | NO               | CONTAINS SQL    | NULL     | DEFINER       | 2018-01-12 15:18:20 | 2018-01-12 15:18:20 | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |                 | root@localhost | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I wonder if it is possible to view the output in a terminal emulator as a nice table like this one?

Comment: Possible workaround [here](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01BMES072/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Using `mysql`'s `ego` command

From `mysql`'s `help` command:

> ego          (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.

So by appending a `\G` to your `select`, you can get a very clean vertical output:

```
mysql> select * from routines where routine_name = "simpleproc" \G
```

### Using a pager

You can tell MySQL to use the `less` pager with its `-S` option that chops wide lines and gives you an output that you can scroll with the arrow keys:

```
mysql> pager less -S
```

Thus, next time you run a command with a wide output, MySQL will let you browse the output with the `less` pager:

```
mysql> select * from routines where routine_name = "simpleproc";
```

If you're done with the pager and want to go back to the regular output on `stdout`, use this:

```
mysql> nopager
```

Comment: Thanks. `\G` will solve the problem when there is only one record in the query result. If there are multiple records in the query results,  will you still use `\G`?

Comment: Sure! `\G` uses a header to separate each record. Between the first and second rows, you will have a line like this one to warn you that it's the second row which is shown below: `*************************** 2. row ***************************`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also adjusting the font size of the terminal but displaying the output vertically should be clear if all doesn't.
use the /G option to run the query i.e

```
mysql> select * from routines where routine_name = "simpleproc" \G
```

Comment: It is backslash not slash