# How can I show the output of psql commands correctly in a terminal emulator?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using `psql` command line client in terminal emulator lxterminal in Ubuntu. When I run the following command the output is mess

```
students=# select * from information_schema.routines;
```

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to view the output in a terminal emulator as a nice table? Thanks.

p.s. Here is a similar question for `mysql`:  [How can I show the output of mysql commands correctly in a terminal emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272997/how-can-i-show-the-output-of-mysql-commands-correctly-in-a-terminal-emulator/48273048).

Comment: `\x` for extened output

Comment: This might help as well: https://github.com/okbob/pspg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display select results vertically in psql, as is done by MySQL's \G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407860/display-select-results-vertically-in-psql-as-is-done-by-mysqls-g)

Answer (score 2):

for "vertical" display, use `\x`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

> -x
>
> --expanded
>
> Turn on the expanded table formatting mode. This is equivalent to \x or \pset expanded.